# Angular 6 pass service to parent class

Tags: angular6

I want to abstracted my component so I have base class:

```
class BaseClass{
  protected data: any;
  protected service: any;

  construct(service){
    this.service = service;
  }
}
```

And the child:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-com',
})
export class Com extends BaseClass implements OnInit {

  constructor() { super(SomeService); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe(x => this.data = x)
  }
}
```

But I get error that

```
getAll() is not a function
```

How correctly pass the service to the parent class?

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution.

In child class:

```
constructor(protected s: SomeService) { super(s); }
```

But is this a good solution?

Comment: In the base class construct must be constructor. Apart from that your code is ok.

Comment: yea, little mistake ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

> But is this a good solution?

Yes, when extending a parent service you are forced to pass all services needed by the parent via the parents constructor.

Other frameworks, may also allow [property/method injection](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html), but this is not natively supported by angular.